2 references required but space for 3. Should I leave it blank?
My Masters application only asks for 2 references, and both my references have agreed to give me one. But there is space for 3 names. Should I leave it blank? I don't really have anyone else to ask and it did not mention to incliude a third anywhere on the website/ admissions, etc.
What do I do?



Do you see adding a non reference person being beneficial?

@Aruralreader I don't think so. My 2 references are pretty strong since they are both academic (what the program wants) and relate to research I did/ concepts in the field. It doesn't mention anywhere to have 3 references, and the program webpage (in the pic) says "Two Letters of Recommendation". I think maybe it may be how the page is laid out, and you fill in 2 or 3 depending on program requirements, but im not sure

If you don't have anyone completely supportive, then yes, leave it blank. A mediocre recommendation won't help.
Requiring three is pretty common though, so make sure you got it right.

It hasn't mentioned anywhere to include 3. I'm assuming the 3rd is for a 'backup' It says this: provide contact information for academic referees from university faculty. Applicants should name referees who are capable of speaking to their experience and interest in the research stream. Applicants who have been out of school for 5 years or less should provide at least one name of academic referee from university faculty and one professional reference. Applicants who have been out of school for more than 5 years should provide at least 1 name of an academic referee from the university faculty.
